# How to include bold math symbols using \bm in glossary?

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra, bm

I want to include a bold math symbol like `\bm{u}` in the glossary. But I don't know how to get it to work. My code is the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[acronym,symbols,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,automake,toc=true,section]{glossaries-extra}

%The entry i want in the glossary
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Control vector}]{\bm{u}}{\ensuremath{\bm{u}}}

\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,sort=use,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]

\begin{document}
$\gls{\bm{u}}$
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a string of characters for the “name” of the symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[
  acronym,
  symbols,
  nogroupskip,
  nonumberlist,
  toc=true,
  section
]{glossaries-extra}

%The entry i want in the glossary
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Control vector}]{bmu}{\ensuremath{\bm{u}}}

\makenoidxglossaries

\begin{document}

\printnoidxglossary[
  type=symbols,
  sort=use,
  style=long,
  title={List of Symbols}
]

\section{Some title}

Here I use it $\gls{bmu}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!